# Changing the template for inline math mode in TeXStudio

Tags: templates, texstudio

Does anybody know how to change the template for "inline math mode"? The default is when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> is creates the following `$`   `$` (two dollar signs a **three** spaces between them an places the cursor in the middle).

I would like to change it to `$$` (two dollar signs an **no** spaces in between and place the cursor in the middle).

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't mind compiling the source code of texstudio yourself, you can change the template. When you've downloaded the source with `hg clone http://hg.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/hg texstudio-hg`, you edit the file `uiconfig.xml`, search for a line that contains the word `mathmode`, change in that line `$ %| $` to `$%|$`, then `make; make install`. Afterwards it's not possible to change the template anymore, as the XML file is "compiled" into a CPP file with the Qt resource compiler and later on compiled and linked into the final executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t know if it is possible to change the predefined template, but you can add a user macro and assign a shortcut to it. To create the script go to Macros > edit macros (I got only the german version, but it should be named equally):

[image: edit macros]

and add a new “normal” script (mine is called “Inlinemathe”):

```
$%<math%>$
```

[image: new script]

you can replace `math` by whatever you want it is the text shown, when triggering the script. After creating the new script you must assign a short cut in Preferences > Short cuts > Macros

[image: assign shortcut]

You can read more about user macros and scripts in the manual, which is available via the Help menu …

Comment: Changing the predefined template is currently not possible.

Answer (score 8):

I used to follow Tobi's method for replacing the inline-math mode, until I found out how I can configure the default mapping. It's very easy actually :)

1. Go to *Options* Menu > Tick "*Show Advanced Options*" at the bottom (inline with *OK* and *Cancel* buttons).
2. In Texstudio *Options* list on the left, choose *Menus*.
3. Go to *Math* (3rd top-level entry) > *Inline math mode*.
4. Replace the command with this (just remove the space on both sides):  `$%|$`
5. That's it. The %| is used to denote that the cursor will be placed there :)

I am late to the party, but hope it helps someone. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Akhilesh, I cannot verify your answer [no longer using that editor], but thanks for contributing :) Welcome to the community!

Comment: Sure. I should thank you for asking this question rather, since I remember consulting this page when I first had this problem :)

Comment: @AkhileshSiddhanti: I have been looking for the exactly same thing and *Menus* would have been most likely the last place I would have looked into for this issue. Thank you for posting this, it works like a charm (of course) :-) +1 from me.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :)

Comment: Recent versions of Texstudio have a slight modification. In 4.2.2, go to `Options -> Configure TeXstudio` and check the `Show Advanced Options` checkbox on the bottom left corner.

Comment: Works very well!